# Is it possible to mark an S3 object to be automatically deleted in the future?

Tags: boto3

I'm processing many S3 Documents, and I'd like to mark them for deletion once they have been deleted, but in the future (one hour from now). This is because once they have been processed, they need to remain available for a while before being deleted.

I saw about the lifecycle system for the bucket, but this is a per S3 object basis as it depends on when they have been processed.

I saw that Boto3 provide the "Expires" metadata, but the description mention the object not being cacheable, so I'm not sure it would mean deleting it.

Is there an effective way to update a S3 object to be removed at a certain date (or in a specific amount of seconds from now)?

Comment: If they are process, one not move them to different bucket with a lifecycle policy?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your suggestion but if it is to move the file to another bucket, the issue will be that the running processes won't be able to find it anymore.

Comment: Why would it be needed after it has been processed. You want to delete it. You can always check second bucket as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on the bucket versioning and when you delete the object, it wlll not deleted but add the deletion marker. You can also set the lifecycle policy for the deletion marker to keep how ling that object. See [Documentations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/DeleteMarker.html)